# No "Reinstall Ubuntu" option in installer (Ubuntu 16.04.2)

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, lvm

It just says: This computer currently has no detected OS. And I have option to erase disc and install.

When I go to "something else" I find something strange:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwjNsJaL6mIIMFFFS29nRkRON2M/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwjNsJaL6mIIV1ZNanRwT00wd0E/view?usp=drivesdk

I have one OS installed (Ubuntu 16.04) on a single partition. At least that is the option I chose in installer, but it seemed to made a lot of strange (to me) partition.

I need to reinstall and keep as much of data, programs and settings possible.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the original system is using LVM, and adding the tag LVM.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea why installer did this. I have added LVM tag.